# Change image randomly when hover

Tags: javascript, image, random, hover

i want to change an image randomly when hovering. The Hover effect is working but when the mouse moves out the image does not change back. Any ideas?

```
var arr = ["020", "053", "306", "035", "930"];

function getRandomImage() {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

  return arr[index];

}

$(function(){
$(".size-woocommerce_thumbnail").hover(function(){
    var image = getRandomImage();
    $(this).attr("srcset", function(index, attr){
        return attr.replace("070", image);
    });
    $(this).attr("src", function(index, attr){
        return attr.replace("070", image);
    });
}, function(){
    $(this).attr("srcset", function(index, attr){
        return attr.replace(image, "070");
    });
    $(this).attr("src", function(index, attr){
        return attr.replace(image, "070");
    });
});
});
```

Comment: I think In the second function inside hover you don't even need to use replace, just set the attribute to "070" as it is the default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the console show any error? My guess is that the scope of `var image = getRandomImage();` is the callback function executed on hover, so `image` is undefined when the second function is executed on mouseout.

My suggestion is to save the value of `image` in a data-* attribute to read on mouseout, something like

```
$(".size-woocommerce_thumbnail").hover(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var image = getRandomImage();
  $this.attr("srcset", function(index, attr){
    return attr.replace("070", image);
  });
  $this.attr("src", function(index, attr){
    return attr.replace("070", image);
  });
  $this.data('image', image);
}, function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var image = $this.data('image');
  $this.attr("srcset", function(index, attr){
      return attr.replace(image, "070");
  });
  $this.attr("src", function(index, attr){
      return attr.replace(image, "070");
  });
});
```

Extra tip: you should save the value of $(this) instead of executing it every time, to avoid recreating the jQuery object. Functions could be chained as well.